# Use Noveau NVIDIA driver instead of proprietary driver

Tags: nvidia, video

I would like to try the Noveau driver instead of the proprietary NVIDIA driver. No problem with the proprietary one, but I would like to see a proper Linux Kubuntu splash screen, which requires kernel graphics support.

Please provide me with a solution so I can "go back" to proprietary if the open ones can't support Google Earth for example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Ubuntu 12.10.  If so, open the program Software Sources.  Click the Additional Drivers tab and select the Noveau Driver from the list.  Click the Apply Changes button.  After it's finished, reboot the system and you should be running the open source drivers.

Answer (score 0):

i guess once you enable closed drivers you automatically deactivate the open ..Deactivating closed driver will make open driver to work, vice versa